# Need to remove a product page statement

Tags: product, attributes, attribute-set, page

There is a statement that needs to be removed from all products that are in 1 attribute set. It is not located in the short description but is located just below. Thoughts on where I might find and remove that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Use default.xml remove statement . Read more on magento devdocs.
Another way is to extend/ rewrite catalog_product_view.xml
And use remove statement too.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you responding. However, Im not a developer so only deal with the "front end" of Magento (1.9). I can't seem to find where this "special note" for these products is located. The commonality I have found is that they all share the same attribute set.